# Have different contacts for different sides of a node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game where you have to control a boat and you have to be the last boat alive. See, the way I want the game to run is that when the front of your boat hits the side or back of another boat it "kills" the other boat, and vice-versa. So far, I have found no ways to do this based on the different sides of the node. I tried to implement this by adding small, invisible nodes on the sides and front of the boat, however, this caused a lot of glitches where the boat would move apart from the hitboxes for a split second while colliding with random objects. Here's my code so far:

```
 func addApple(_ position: CGPoint) {

    guard let appleImage = UIImage(named: "apple") else {
        return
    }

    let texture = SKTexture(image: appleImage)
    let apple = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
    apple.position = position
    apple.setScale(0.1)
    addChild(apple)
    appleNode = apple
}
 addApple(CGPoint(x: -100, y: -100))
```

then I have this for adding the CPU boat

```
 locationx2 = (appleNodeCpu?.position.x)!
    locationy2 = (appleNodeCpu?.position.y)!
    let dx2 = locationx2 - (appleNodeCpu2?.position.x)!
    let dy2 = locationy2 - (appleNodeCpu2?.position.y)!
    let angle2 = atan2(dy2, dx2)
    let vx2 = cos(angle2) * appleNodeCpu2Speed
    let vy2 = sin(angle2) * appleNodeCpu2Speed
```

and then for moving the boat:

```
      moveAnalogStick.beginHandler = { [unowned self] in


        guard self.appleNode != nil else {
            return
        }

    }



    moveAnalogStick.trackingHandler = { [unowned self] jData in
        let rotateToAngle = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: jData.angular, duration:0.25, shortestUnitArc:true)

        self.appleNode?.run(rotateToAngle)

        guard let aN = self.appleNode else {
            return
        }
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.25 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

          aN.position = CGPoint(x: aN.position.x + (jData.velocity.x * 0.12), y: aN.position.y + (jData.velocity.y * 0.12))
        }

    }

    moveAnalogStick.stopHandler =  { [unowned self] in

        guard self.appleNode != nil else {
            return
        }

    }
```

That's just my code for ADDING the ships to the scene, moving it around works perfectly, however, I have no idea how to go about creating these different contacts. Sorry :(

Thank you for any help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an SKPhysicsBody to each ship and then use the built-in contact and collision detection mechanism that provides, see [Working With Collisions and Contacts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody#1654742).

On a simpler level, you could just test when two nodes intersect using the [SKNode.intersects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483140-intersects) method.